# Sorting images in images hosting and sharing website

Tags: website-design, image, sort

We are building an image hosting and sharing website, there will be a page where user can see all photos uploaded by website users.

In this page the user can sort the photos by votes, most comments, most viewed.

First issues we are thinking about is, which sort should be the default when the user open the page for the first time?

We thought to be the most voted, but this may keep the same photos on the page for some days and may be months without big change. also the same apply to most comments and most viewed may be.

What is the best practice to do this page and its sorting.

*My page will be something like this: http://vi.sualize.us/popular/ put with more sorting options.*

Answer (score 3):

**For a user to see his own photos:**

I'll go for the "last uploaded" first default sort options and then I'll go for the "last sort" chosen by the user that could be stored on the client part.

The last uploaded is the default behaviour for most of image browsing apps because it is the more personal (if you group properly, all photos for one holidays will be together for instance) and the more relevant for the owner of the photos' owner.

**For all others users:**

I'll go for some clever groups like on the same page:

- "Popular photos" (most viewed)
- "Best photos" (most rated)
- "Last photos" (last uploaded)

And you can refine those categories by setting some period constraints "Popular today, this week, this month"

Answer (score 0):

I think the default sort can be latest uploaded instead of most voted, as user always wants to view the new pics and also gives the feeling of the content getting constantly updated.

And then you can have Editors Choice/Most Viewed/